# How to add alarm with specified user defined date and time? Android studio

Tags: java, android, alarm

I want to make a pill reminder app. I created date and time picker. Under this i created "SET ALARM" button.  But i want to add pill reminder with pop up window after clicking set alarm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AlarmManager like:

```
private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +
        60 * 1000, alarmIntent);
```

More info You will find here:
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms#java